# small issue with javascript

Tags: javascript, function

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function blz()
{
//alert("asdf");
//document.getElementById("link").innerHTML='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=172099656214641&link='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("product").value)+'&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fsocial.gogmat.com%2Fimages%2Flogo_03.jpg&name='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("subject").value)+'&caption=Invitation%20to%20checkout%20product%20on%20Gogmat&description=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A'+encodeURI(document.getElementById("message").value)+'&message=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A'+encodeURI(document.getElementById("message").value)+'&redirect_uri='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("redirect").value);

document.getElementById("link").innerHTML=encodeURI("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=172099656214641&link="+document.getElementById("product").value+"&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fsocial.gogmat.com%2Fimages%2Flogo_03.jpg&name="+document.getElementById("subject").value+"&caption=Invitation%20to%20checkout%20product%20on%20Gogmat&description=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A"+document.getElementById("message").value+"&message=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A"+document.getElementById("message").value+"&redirect_uri="+document.getElementById("redirect").value);

//document.getElementById('button1').href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=172099656214641&link='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("product").value)+'&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fsocial.gogmat.com%2Fimages%2Flogo_03.jpg&name='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("subject").value)+'&caption=Invitation%20to%20checkout%20product%20on%20Gogmat&description=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A'+encodeURI(document.getElementById("message").value)+'&message=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A'+encodeURI(document.getElementById("message").value)+'&redirect_uri='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("redirect").value);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
subject:<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="" onkeyup="return blz()" /><br/>
personal message:<input type="text" id="message" name="message" value="" onkeyup="return blz()" /><br/>
select product for recommend:<input type="text" id="product" name="product" value="" onkeyup="return blz()" /><br/>
link return:<input type="text" id="return" name="return" value="" onkeyup="return blz()" /><br/>
<textarea id="link" name="link" rows="10" cols="40" readonly></textarea><br/>
<a id="button1" href="" target="_blank"><img src="http://social.gogmat.com/components/com_referal/assets/images/bg_send.gif" alt="send button" /></a><br/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

what might be problem in this, am facing the problem with the above code, it is not showing the text inside the textarea or href part of the anchor tag, am in total confusion for the first time about this regard in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No element with an id of "redirect" is not present in your document. so it's causing a javascript error.

I have added the missing element with a value of "bleh" to demonstrate.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function blz()
{

//document.getElementById("link").innerHTML='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=172099656214641&link='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("product").value)+'&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fsocial.gogmat.com%2Fimages%2Flogo_03.jpg&name='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("subject").value)+'&caption=Invitation%20to%20checkout%20product%20on%20Gogmat&description=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A'+encodeURI(document.getElementById("message").value)+'&message=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A'+encodeURI(document.getElementById("message").value)+'&redirect_uri='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("redirect").value);

var aurl = encodeURI("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=172099656214641&link="+document.getElementById("product").value+"&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fsocial.gogmat.com%2Fimages%2Flogo_03.jpg&name="+document.getElementById("subject").value+"&caption=Invitation%20to%20checkout%20product%20on%20Gogmat&description=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A"+document.getElementById("message").value+"&message=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A"+document.getElementById("message").value+"&redirect_uri="+document.getElementById("redirect").value);
document.getElementById("link").value = aurl;

//document.getElementById('button1').href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=172099656214641&link='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("product").value)+'&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fsocial.gogmat.com%2Fimages%2Flogo_03.jpg&name='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("subject").value)+'&caption=Invitation%20to%20checkout%20product%20on%20Gogmat&description=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A'+encodeURI(document.getElementById("message").value)+'&message=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A'+encodeURI(document.getElementById("message").value)+'&redirect_uri='+encodeURI(document.getElementById("redirect").value);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
<input type="text" name="redirect" id="redirect" value="bleh" />
subject:<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="" onkeyup="return blz()" /><br/>
personal message:<input type="text" id="message" name="message" value="" onkeyup="return blz()" /><br/>
select product for recommend:<input type="text" id="product" name="product" value="" onkeyup="return blz()" /><br/>
link return:<input type="text" id="return" name="return" value="" onkeyup="return blz()" /><br/>
<textarea id="link" name="link" rows="10" cols="40" readonly></textarea><br/>
<a id="button1" href="" target="_blank"><img src="http://social.gogmat.com/components/com_referal/assets/images/bg_send.gif" alt="send button" /></a><br/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Another solution would be to remove `document.getElementById("redirect").value` from your string.

Comment: He did have a `<textarea>` with the id "link", but it's in the `<body>` *after* the `<script>` block.

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of a `<textarea>`, you update its "value" attribute:

```
document.getElementById("link").value = encodeURI("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=172099656214641&link="+document.getElementById("product").value+"&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fsocial.gogmat.com%2Fimages%2Flogo_03.jpg&name="+document.getElementById("subject").value+"&caption=Invitation%20to%20checkout%20product%20on%20Gogmat&description=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A"+document.getElementById("message").value+"&message=Check%20this%20product%20on%20social.gogmat.com%20now.%0A"+document.getElementById("message").value+"&redirect_uri="+document.getElementById("redirect").value);
```

Comment: still not successful with your idea. but thanks for replying

Comment: Well, it definitely works, but you also have to do what @silverstrike said and move your `<script>` block to the end of the `<body>`, or else run that code in an "onload" handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the function after the element you are searching has finished loading (onload event, or placing the script tags after the element's closing tag).

Comment: i tried with your ideas also but didnt got luck